# How to debug form submit ajaxsubmit(ajaxOptions)?

Tags: jquery, ajaxsubmit

See below code, `$('#form').valid()` is `true` but data === 'validation_error'.

Anyone could tell me how to debug to find out why I got the validation error even form is valid?

```
App.SubmitApplication = () => {
    $('#form').submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        
        if ($('#form').valid()) {
            let ajaxOptions = {
                beforeSend: () => {
                    helperApp.BlockUI('js-pnl-application');
                },
                success: (data) => {
                    if (data === 'validation_error') {
                        //show validation error
                    }
                    //show SUCCESS
                 },
                 error: (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    //An error happened when saving your data.");
                 }
             };
             
             $('#form').ajaxSubmit(ajaxOptions);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Looks like the response from your service.  ie your service is incorrectly returning a 200 response with the text `"validation_error"`

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly happen?  how could I debug this?

Comment: Start with F12, network tab.  Run your app.   Inspect the response.  Next, debug/step-through your service (server-side) code.

Comment: It did not really reach the server-side code.  It just stop in the js part ..  Failed on line (data === 'validation_error')  but I do not know why it pass the form validation and failed in the data ....  thanks

Comment: The `success:` callback is when the ajax response has completed.  Perhaps ajaxSubmit is doing something strange.

Comment: interesting.  The application will display the error message which put under the (data === 'validation_error') condition.  I could alert the value of data and it is validation_error'.  So when submit the form, it will submit validation_error' instead of real data.

Comment: I used F12 and it show me some great information.  thank you for your help!!!!